# Quote an unquoted text in R

Tags: r

Let's say I want to transform the following text into a character vector:

```
ACOT13,BIRC6,BOD1L1,CALM3,CDC42,CEP350,CIAO1,CLTA,CLTC,DIAPH1,DYNC2I1,DYNLL1,HAUS8,INO80,KIF22,KIFC1,MAD1L1,MAPK1,NSFL1C,NUP62,PLK3,PRC1,PRPF19,RMDN3,SEPTIN2,TUBG1,WDR62
```

The elements are already separated by `,` so all I need is to quote every element of this text e.g. the first one quoted would be `"ACOT13"`.

I know I could write this text into a file and then read the file but i was thinking if there is a way to do that directly in r without writing the text into a file.

Comment: the `datapasta` package provides utilities to convert  text in, say, an editor, to a character vector, and shortcuts can be added to do so. Copying the input to the clipboard and either calling `vector_paste()` manually or using its shortcut, will place a formatted character vector in the editor

Comment: Alternatively make a function that takes symbols and converts to string `formatter <- function(...){ ll <- rlang::ensyms(...) ; lapply(ll, rlang::as_string) |> unlist(use.names = F) }`. `formatter(ACOT13,BIRC6,BOD1L1)` gives  [1] "ACOT13"  "BIRC6"   "BOD1L1". This uses the `rlang` package, but base R alternative exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str <- "ACOT13,BIRC6,BOD1L1,CALM3,CDC42,CEP350,CIAO1,CLTA,CLTC,DIAPH1,DYNC2I1,DYNLL1,HAUS8,INO80,KIF22,KIFC1,MAD1L1,MAPK1,NSFL1C,NUP62,PLK3,PRC1,PRPF19,RMDN3,SEPTIN2,TUBG1,WDR62"
result <- strsplit(str,",")
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you also included the contents of `result`.

Comment: To my understanding this is not what OP asked - manually placing quotes around the text and then isolate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but I think you can just split your comma separated string into smaller strings?

```
mystring <- "ACOT13,BIRC6,BOD1L1,CALM3,CDC42,CEP350,CIAO1,CLTA,CLTC,DIAPH1,DYNC2I1,DYNLL1,HAUS8,INO80,KIF22,KIFC1,MAD1L1,MAPK1,NSFL1C,NUP62,PLK3,PRC1,PRPF19,RMDN3,SEPTIN2,TUBG1,WDR62"

library(stringr) 
str_split(mystring, ',', simplify=TRUE) -> my_vector_of_strings

my_vector_of_strings 
     [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]    [,5]    [,6]     [,7]    [,8]   [,9]
[1,] "ACOT13" "BIRC6" "BOD1L1" "CALM3" "CDC42" "CEP350" "CIAO1" "CLTA" "CLTC"
     [,10]    [,11]     [,12]    [,13]   [,14]   [,15]   [,16]   [,17]
[1,] "DIAPH1" "DYNC2I1" "DYNLL1" "HAUS8" "INO80" "KIF22" "KIFC1" "MAD1L1"
     [,18]   [,19]    [,20]   [,21]  [,22]  [,23]    [,24]   [,25]     [,26]
[1,] "MAPK1" "NSFL1C" "NUP62" "PLK3" "PRC1" "PRPF19" "RMDN3" "SEPTIN2" "TUBG1"
     [,27]
[1,] "WDR62"
```

Or maybe you want to keep the string but replace commas with `","`?

```
my_new_string <- paste0('"',str_replace(mystring, "," , '","'),'"')
```